# Convert String to Java Hashmap

Tags: java

I have a string as below which needs to be converted to HashMap.

```
String datasample="{SessionID=ACVRT5678897DERT, Name=ACFGTYR, Age=34, sessionTime=20210428}"
```

I tried using  Java 8 lambda ,stream and  collect and it works when datasample does not include `"{"` and `"}"`. But My string includes `"{"` and `"}"`.

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Replace the { and} and then split???

Comment: Nevermind, the `=` sign ...

Comment: If your solution works using lambda, why don't you use map() operator to remove all brackets from input string?

Answer (score 1):

If you have code that works when the characters "{" and "}" aren't present then couldn't you just remove these?

```
String dataSample="{SessionID=ACVRT5678897DERT, Name=ACFGTYR, Age=34, sessionTime=20210428}"
sampleToUse = dataSample.substring(1, dataSample.length() - 1);   //Remove 1st and last char
//run sampleToUse through your lambda
```